# Setting up R in Atom: How to Run a Help Page

Tags: r, rstudio, atom-editor, hydrogen

I successfully set up R in my new Atom editor and can get in-line results using the Hydrogen package. I just noticed, however, that when I run lines to obtain "R Documentation" that would pop up automatically in RStudio, Hydrogen only gives me a check mark in-line result with no associated documentation.

Here is what is going on in my Atom editor when I run `?plot`

[image]

Here is what happens in RStudio (bottom right pane), which I am hoping I can get in Atom

[image]

How can I get this working in Atom?

Answer (score 0):

try `hydrogen -> Toggle inspector`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question and actually made a little progress. Perhaps someone more experienced than I can use this to make a package to enable an in-atom help documentation panel for us :)

Anyway you can install the atom package 'script' which will properly output some, but not all, help documents. I have an example of one working & one not working.

[Working ?read.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkNDS.png)

[Not-working ?geom_bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjo4i.png)

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the `script` package?